# Is it possible to have overlapping stack of unordered list like this using CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I need to display the rectangles in an overlapped manner like so:
[image]

My below code is not able to achieve this effect. Can anyone please help?

```css
.location-stack ul{
   list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  .location-stack li{
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-left: 50px;
   border: 2px solid transparent;
   border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   height: 32px;
   outline: none;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
   
   background-color: #fff;
   font-family: Roboto;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-weight: 300;

   padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   width: 500px;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="location-stack">
  <ul>
   <li>Fav 1</li>
   <li>Fav 2</li>
   <li>Fav 3</li>
  </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, elements which appear later in DOM order are displayed in front of previous ones. If you want the opposite, you can use`z-index`.

```css
.location-stack ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
}
.location-stack li {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 5px 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 500px;
}
.location-stack li:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 3;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.location-stack li:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 2;
  margin-left: 60px;
}
.location-stack li:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="location-stack">
  <ul>
    <li>Fav 1</li>
    <li>Fav 2</li>
    <li>Fav 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution is exactly what I wanted. Thanks for prompt response. 1 quick query though: In my problem the no. of <li> is not fixed to 3 and may vary upto 10 <li> rendered dynamically. How will you solve that problem as I can see you have hardcoded the nth-child

Comment: @sunny_dev You could reverse the items in the source (i.e. 3, 2, 1) and then make them display in reversed order than in the source (i.e. 1, 2, 3). This way the first one will be displayed on top and you won't need to set the `z-index` for each one. To reverse you can use `writing-mode: sideways-lr`. For the margin I was thinking some float hacks. But this is all too unstable, when I was trying things the browser did different things depending on in which order I set or unset the things. So better use JS.